# Why is this proof correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Sometimes in proofs I find that authors assume the existence of something in the first place before proving some property.

Here is an example, imho,  from  "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler:

> **(4.5) Division algorithm for polynomials**
>
> Suppose p, q $ \in \mathcal P (F) $ with $ p \neq 0$. Then there exists polynomials s,r such that $$ (4.6) q=sp+r $$ and $ \text{Deg r} \lt \text{Deg p}$

And the proof:

> Choose s $\in \mathcal P(F)$ such that q-sp has degree as small as possible. Let r=q-sp. Thus 4.6 holds and all that remains to show is that $ \text{Deg r} \lt \text{Deg p}$ . Now suppose that $ \text{Deg r} \ge \text{Deg p}$ . If $c \in F$ and j is a non-negative integer then $$ q-(s+cz^j)p = r-cz^jp$$ Now choose j and c so that the RHS has degree strictly less than r . This contradicts our choice of s as the polynomial such that q-sp has degree as small as possible.

But surely the first sentence presupposes the existence of such an $s$ in the first place ?

Comment: Suppose you had a set of polynomials $S\subseteq k[X]$, what would would happen if there didn't exist a polynomial with minimum degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{\deg(q-sp):s\in\mathcal{P}(F)\}$ is a non-empty set of positive integers (possibly including zero as well).

By the Well-ordering principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle), the set must contain a least element.

Comment: But it says in the book that $0$ has degree -infinity ?

Comment: Yes, that is a valid point. So the set is a subset of $\{-\infty, 0\}\cup\mathbb{N}$, which is still well-ordered, that is, any non-empty subset has a least element.